# Why is this question "How to refer to a specific definite person whose gender is unknown" duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Why is this question "*How to refer to a specific definite person whose gender is unknown*" duplicate?[How to refer to a specific definite person whose gender is unknown](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48243/how-to-refer-to-a-specific-definite-person-whose-gender-is-unknown)

It does not ask whether a non-specific indefinite person like anybody or somebody as "they" is grammatical or not.
It asks whether a specific definite person like the murderer of a certain murder case whose gender is unknown as "they" is grammatical or not.

"Somebody" is not a specific definite person.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing the difference; even if the questions aren't exactly the same, I think the same answers apply, whether the "they" refers to "somebody" or "the murderer".

Comment: @J.R. Somebody is a non-specific indefinite person while the murderer is a specific definite person.
Wikipedia says:
"*In informal spoken English, plural pronouns are often used with indefinite pronoun antecedents.*"
"*Somebody should let you borrow their book.*"
However, I'm not sure if the sentence "*Leslie should let you borrow their book.*" is grammatical even in informal spoken English,
where Leslie is the name of a person whose gender may or may not be known.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I can say of a murderer – especially if the crime is unsolved: _They killed the victim, they should do the time_. It's grammatical. That's why your question was closed, because the answer at the first question also answers your question, even if your question has a slight plot twist. (By the way, it's also grammatical to talk about Leslie or Robin or anyone else who should let me borrow their book. Sentences aren't rendered ungrammatical just because I can't discern the gender, and the plural pronoun works as a stand-in when needed.)

Comment: @J.R. Could you show some evidences to support your claim that a sentence like "*The murderer has written it with their own blood.*" or "Leslie should let you borrow their book.*" is grammatical?

Comment: Not here; comments are not an appropriate place for that sort of thing. You really ought to spend some time editing your question, explaining why you're not satisfied with the answer at that other question, and that you would specifically want to see examples in literature to support claims that the construct is valid and used today. Then the question can be reopened and more answers can be left there.

Comment: @J.R. "*Not here;*"
If the question is duplicate, where is the answer?
There's none because it is not duplicate.

Comment: Fine. Make that more obvious by editing your question, and providing more information about what you seek in the question itself. Then it will be reopened.

Comment: @J.R. "*Fine. Make that more obvious by editing your question, and providing more information about what you seek in the question itself.*"

I clearly stated that referring to someone as they is grammatical at least in informal speech.
What should be made more obvious?

"*I think that referring to a non-specific indefinite person like everyone, anyone, someone etc. as "they" is grammatical and widely accepted as being natural at least in informal speech. For example, the sentence "Everyone did their best" is grammatical.*"

Comment: What should be made more obvious? _What you are trying to ask._ You asked the question, the community thought it already had an answer, and you disagree. The best way to get the community to see that your question is different is by **editing the question** and making it more clear.

Comment: @J.R. As if closing a question is *always* justified.
Please let me emphasize this just in case: It takes *only* five votes to close a question. I'm saying this because you're a *moderator* who I believe should be particularly *neutral* and *fair*.

Comment: Your question got closed almost 24 hours ago. Right after you asked it, you wrote in a comment: "You don't seem to understand the question." An hour later, another comment: "You still don't understand my question." Now I've asked you, almost implored you: edit your question – make it more understandable. Sure, it takes _only_ five votes to close a question, but it only takes five votes to reopen a question, too. (And, just between me and you, this moderator has been hoping to speed that up all day long.) Yet still the question remains unedited...

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question/225024#225024).

Comment: @J.R. "*Now I've asked you, almost implored you: edit your question – make it more understandable.*"
I asked: "*Is the sentence "The murderer has written it with their own blood." grammatical in present-day English?*"
What exactly do you not understand about this question?

Comment: Makoto, if you're not interested in at least making an effort into improving your question, then I'm not interested in reopening it. All is not lost, though: Perhaps five people will weed through all the comments here and there and see the light and vote to reopen.

Comment: @J.R. Please explain what's wrong with my question.
Otherwise I cannot improve it.

Comment: I would start by adding a link to the "duplicate" question, and then paraphrase what is established there. (_"I already know X..."_) Then, explain how you are asking about something clearly different. Make it obvious that you're aware of the answer at the other question, and you are asking about something entirely different. (_"...but I am asking about Y."_) In other words, something along [these lines](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14024). Also [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224584) on ELU.

Comment: @J.R. Have you read my question in the main?
The question is not duplicate at all: 
*I think that referring to a non-specific indefinite person like everyone, anyone, someone etc. as "they" is grammatical and widely accepted as being natural at least in informal speech. For example, the sentence "Everyone did their best" is grammatical. However, what about referring to a specific definite person?*